# How do I update the data attribute of the video without page refresh?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with changing the data attribute value of the video

```html
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Video ID" id="input" />
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button">Watch</button>
  <br />
</div>
<div class="video-player">
  <video
    id="video"
    style="width: 800px"
    class="youtube-video-1"
    data-yt="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Amq-qlqbjYA"
  ></video>
</div>
```

```js
$('#button').on({
    'click': function(){
       var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
       $('#video').attr('data-yt', "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + inputvalue );
    }
});
```

This is just one of the methods i have tried but no luck

Comment: Would src attribute not help?

Comment: Aside from what is little more than a type (the `on` method takes two arguments, not an object as a single argument) that code will update the `data-yt` attribute just fine. You appear to have an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The question you appear to be trying to ask is **How can I change the video loaded by my unspecified library after it has loaded and read the data attribute from which it receives the initial URL?**

Comment: the source for the video is automatically generated by the data-yt attribute because the source is a dynamic link which keeps changing so basically i want to get the complete url of the youtube video or just the id from the input field and update the data-yt attribute @Quentin

Comment: @YeshwanthB — So your **end goal** is to update the `data-yt` attribute? It isn't to influence any JS that **reads** that attribute? And which might have **already** read it and will never read it **again**? (If so, then the problem is just the typo I pointed out previously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and it's successfully updates `data-yt` attribute:
[your example](https://codepen.io/biomagic/pen/MWmOQON)

And there is working variant with `iframe` instead `video` but updates `src` attribute instead `data-yt`: [video in iframe](https://codepen.io/biomagic/pen/poPdaaX)

Comment: Thank you this is the exact output i was looking for